# Auto assign script based on 2 different criteria in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

hope you can help me with this one. I have zero background in writing script and I am currently at loss and thought ask some help here while researching in youtube for some answer. I'm more of a visual learner, and dissecting an already working script might be more productive in my case.

The ask:

I am trying to create a script that automatically assign the tasks on Gotham and Metropolis
divided equally from the number of heroes on HQ. I also need to shuffle the task and the hero to make it randomize.

All data are updated daily using importrange formula from another sheet.

Thanks!

Here's the sample sheets:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SmTbOth9-JtoG1-NMjICzE1iB27mpa5vW1I0P2_-71Y/edit?usp=sharing
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gr0Y4nKfnctUtO7EW-NSHangypCbVjPZ620xxW3b6Y8/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

That can be done with a spreadsheet formula without resorting to scripting. Put these formulas in the 'Auto populate' spreadsheet:

In cell `Gotham!B2`:

```
=lambda( 
  tasks, recalculate, 
  lambda( 
    randomIndices, 
    sort(tasks, randomIndices, true) 
  )( 
    randarray(rows(tasks)) 
  ) 
)( 
  filter(A2:A, len(A2:A)), 
  D1 
)
```

In cell `Gotham!C2`:

```
=lambda( 
  heroes, numTasks, recalculate, 
  lambda( 
    heroesShuffled, 
    map( 
      sequence(numTasks, 1, 0), 
      lambda( 
        i, 
        index(heroesShuffled, mod(i, rows(heroesShuffled)) + 1) 
      ) 
    ) 
  )( 
    sort(heroes, randarray(rows(heroes)), true) 
  ) 
)( 
  filter(HQ!A4:A, len(HQ!A4:A)), 
  rows(filter(A2:A, len(A2:A))), 
  D1 
)
```

Alternatively, to assign tasks randomly without attempting to balance the number of tasks per hero, use this formula in cell `Gotham!C2`:

```
=lambda( 
  heroes, tasks, recalculate, 
  lambda( 
    randomIndices, 
    map( 
      randomIndices, 
      lambda( 
        randomIndex, 
        if( 
          len("recalc" & recalculate), 
          index(heroes, mod(randomIndex, rows(heroes)) + 1) 
        ) 
      ) 
    ) 
  )( 
    arrayformula( roundup(randarray(rows(tasks)) * rows(tasks) ) ) 
  ) 
)( 
  filter(HQ!A4:A, len(HQ!A4:A)), 
  filter(A2:A, len(A2:A)), 
  D1 
)
```

You may want to **Insert > Checkbox** in cell `D1`. When you want to regenerate the lists, click the checkbox.

To permanently fix the shuffled results in place, copy the results with **Control+V** and paste them as values only with **Control+Shift+V**.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked amazingly! However, I noticed one glaring problem, the heroes were not shuffled. It is perfect if the number of task is equally divided by the number of heroes, but if not, Aquaman will be overwork while he is at the top of the list since new task is updated everyday. 

I've also love to have a checkbox that sort the heroes tasks together for ease of use, I've tried query but it doesn't seem to capture alphanumberic tasks.

Comment: Upon further checking, the task keeps on shuffling every time the worksheet is loaded/refreshes.

Comment: Yes, @doubleunary. I'm new here, is there a way for the task to not shuffle every time the sheets loads/refreshes? Multiple heroes will be opening the sheets to check their daily tasks.

Comment: Appreciate the help, sadly, the formula wont be applicable to what I needed to do.
It keeps on shuffling on my end every time I refresh the sheet.
I can't post gif yet, so here's the link:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zv8dt.gif

Comment: I've done some testing and it seems like the formula itself has some issues with importrange, unfortunately the data I need is coming from another sheet.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean my importrange but, I've asked someone to use it on their importrange and still not working.
The formula must not been compatible to be used on data pulled using importrange which I specifically stated in my original question and were I've attached two separate sheets also to show as such.

Comment: You can fix the results in place so that they never change using the **paste values only** routine mentioned at the end of the answer. The source data comes through importrange and therefore gets refreshed from time to time, even when the values therein remain the same. Your question fails to specify that the results must never ever be recalculated even when the source data is updated. That requirement makes this is a different question that will require a different solution. If paste values only does not work for you, post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).